# How to implement locks in when using transactions in codeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions, locking

I want to **lock** updating of a table in **codeIgniter** when using **transaction**. Can anybody help me how to implement it?

The problem is this that when to people want to update a table at same time, it getting error and the second one is not updated until submitting form again (saying duplicate id...).